# No module called Pandas on the just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and PyCharm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, python3

I was with assumption that Ubuntu has all the packages needed for Python. I mean Python3. I installed PyCharm. I just ran this `import pandas as pd`, got the `no module found` error. I am surprized. Does it mean I have to install all packages from scratch? If so, how to install them?

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ubuntu does not come with every possible python package already installed.  It has core python modules installed but `pandas` is NOT a core python package. It's a third party library.

You should take some time to understand virtual environments.  Make sure you have ubuntu packages `python3-pip` `python3-wheel` `python3-venv` all installed through apt:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-wheel python3-venv
```

Then create your virtual environment with:

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install pandas
```

You can then configure pycharm to use this virtual environment which is now stored in a directory named `venv`.

Comment: I just updated my question with a screenshot. Looks like `python3-pip` is not available.

Comment: @Mainland `python3-pip` is the apt package name the command is `pip3` and depending on how it is setup maybe just `pip`.  It's needed for the third line of setting up the virtual environment. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Hi, I just posted a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742270/ubuntu-python-pycharm-how-to-use-and-install-new-packages