# Ubuntu Python PyCharm How to use and install new packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, python3

I am beginner to PyCharm. It is driving me crazy just getting to know what is what and how to use it. I followed the instructions based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741935/no-module-called-pandas-on-the-just-installed-ubuntu-22-04-and-pycharm/741942?noredirect=1#comment1409827_741942). But don't know what or why I am doing. But presently it is not working as I wanted. For instance, I was able to import some general python packages into the script. Also, I installed a new package `seaborn` on the terminal, hope I installed it and configured to my project correctly. But I fail to import it in the script.

Packages installed:
[image]

Configuring the environment and Creating a new project
[image]

Attempting to import some packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

Present output:

```
    import seaborn as sns
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Comment: Please don't paste a text terminal as an image; instead copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most Python IDEs these days, PyCharm creates a separate `virtualenv` for each project. A Virtual Environment is essentially an installation of python and various python modules that's entirely independent of the version distributed by the OS.

Alleged reason being that a lot of python modules that people want to use either aren't in official distro repositories yet or the versions are too old.

If you want to install seaborn within that venv, you'll need to install it via `pip` while running with that specific venv enabled, as opposed to the one you seem to have set up in `~/venv`

Comment: I am a beginner here. It isn't very clear to me what to do. Can you please elaborate? If I use `virtualenv`, how to install seaborn into this environment? `pip install seaborn` correct?

Comment: Yes, but the virtualenv in `/home/REDACTED/PycharmProject/venv` is not the same virtualenv as the one in `~/venv/` where you installed seaborn.

Comment: Yes! `pip install seaborn` worked. Thank you